# Take object from list and pass to another method

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

As the title describes, using thymeleaf I display the contents of a list and then I put "Update" buttons next to each item on the list that send the particular object to an editing form page.

Here is the controller method for adding the list to the list view:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(Model model){
        List<Employee> employees = repository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        return "list";
    }
```

And here is the thymeleaf html code:

```
<tr th:each="emp : ${employees}">
            <td th:text="${emp.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${emp.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${emp.surname}"></td>
            <td th:text="${emp.age}"></td>
            <td th:text="${emp.department}"></td>
            <td>
                <form th:action="@{/update}" method = "POST" th:object="${emp}">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{name}" ></input>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{surname}"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{age}"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{department}"></input>
                    <button type = "submit">Update</button>
                </form>
            </td>
</tr>
```

And here is the receiving method:

```
@RequestMapping("/update")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("emp") Employee emp){

        return "update";
    }
```

I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'emp' available as request attribute
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 0):

This could be help.Change your controller like this.Its work for me.

```
model.addAttribute("emp", new Employee());

@RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(Model model){
        List<Employee> employees = repository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("emp", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        return "list";
    }
```

Comment: If i do this, then there is no exception but i send back an empty Employee object.

Comment: But they specify it in the document ion like this .https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/